# How does heavy query on a PosgreSQL read replication affect the writer resources (if any)

Tags: postgresql, report, replication

I'm searching for a solution to run a heavy report script (will run around 1-2 hours) on an Aurora postgresql DB.
We have 2 instances, one is the writer and the second is the reader.
there is a replication between them.
my question is: if I run a very heavy report on the reader can it affect the writer performance? if the answer is yes, what can be the impact?
Thanks in advance,
Michal

no tries. I plan to do some check on a test env later today, but want to hear if someone has experience with such checks

Answer (score 0):

If you configure PostgreSQL correctly, you can do that without any negative impact on the primary server. The solution is to leave `hot_standby_feedback = off` on the standby, but set `max_standby_streaming_delay = -1`.  Then replay of the replicated modifications on the standby can be delayed, but there is no impact on the primary server.

Read [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/) for more detail.